# Converting STL unicode string to wxString gives empty string

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, stl, wxwidgets

My code is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <wx/string.h>
int main(int n, char** c) {
    std::string a = "你好";
    wxString b = a;
    std::cerr <<a.length()<<"/"<< b.Len()<<"\n";
}
```

I would expect the result to be something like "6/6" but I am getting "6/0". That is, b is empty. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried other conversions but they do not work either.

Compiling by:

```
g++ `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` -std=c++11 -o string-test string-test.cpp
```

wx version is 3.0.0.0. gcc version 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1) (GCC).

Comment: Maybe the IDE is using unicode to encode the char but the Wx documentation says that the conversion uses the current locale: this may cause a failure in the conversion. Have you tried using wstring or setting the locale to unicode?

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Converting_everything_to_and_from_wxString), there is a constructor that can specify encoding, e.g.: `wxString b( a.c_str(), wxConvUTF8);`

Comment: `std::string a = "你好";`  I would suggest you debug and inspect the contents of `a` to ensure it is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wxString` uses the current locale for interpreting its input by default and in case of your program this locale is the default "C" as you never change it. Set it to whichever locale corresponds to the encoding used by your source file to allow the code to work as expected as written.

Two much better alternatives would be to:

1. Use `std::wstring = L"..."`.
2. Use `wxString::FromUTF8("...")` if you are confident your sources are always in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, have accepted. As it was, my error was elsewhere (the UTF8 strings in my real program were badly formed).